# TcpListener listening to local network devices

Tags: c#, tcp, lan, tcplistener

Not sure that I am actually using the right terms here.

I'm writing a simple server in C# and using a TcpListener to listen to connection requests. I want to allow only connection requests from (1) my own pc and (2) devices that are connected to the same router as my PC.

Is there anything that already does this or will I have to implement this on my own? (I did not manage to find anything implemented already.)

If I have to implement this on my own, one approach is first calculating valid IPs and then listen on these (and perhaps update the listener every once in a while when devices connect and disconnect from the network). Another approach is simply listening to IPAddress.Any, and when the listener returns a new TcpClient just verify its IP (and perhaps close it if it is not valid).

I'm leaning towards method two, as it seems much simpler to me. I guess this is susceptible to some form of attacks, however.

What is the right way to go here?

Comment: Consinder just using en encrypted connection to make it safe

Comment: Can you please elaborate? How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Just read quickly about this, and it seems like you can use SslStream for that. However, I don't think I will currently use this as this is not intended to be super secure. So I'm back to my original question.

Comment: What you want to do is called Port Forwarding.  Port forwarding requires both ends of the connection to mux and demux data onto one port.  Firewalls often have this feature.  Routers do not have the option.

Comment: I see. So basically my only option is to accept all requests and only after that verify them?

Comment: Consider using a higher level protocol, tcp is a low level protocol that require you to define your own protocol on top. Using a existing high level protocol is easier, since you can use existing libraries and tools, and many includes features for authentication, encryption and security. Statically restricting access to your service is what firewalls are for.